# Problems with server

Tags: java, javascript

I am making a game server, and I have to lead it to Java. I have done that, but it says "The system cannot find the path specified. The path is ""c:\programfiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_25" Which I can follow that right to it, with no problems. So whats wrong?

Yes, I have tried a space.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried putting a space between program and files?

Comment: Usually it's "Program Files" with a space, not "programfiles".

Comment: can you post what your configuration looks like? Where do you set the path to lead it to java?

Comment: You can lead a horse to Java but you can't make him compile.

Answer (score 2):

It's very difficult to determine what you are trying to do right here..

From what it looks like, you are trying to call the program, `jdk1.7.0_25`, when that is not a valid program.

If i'm understanding you correctly, you want to copy all java files from this directory (`.`) to the jdk folder. to do that, use

```
@echo off
COLOR 08
title Compiler
cp ./*.java "c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_25"
pause
```

If i'm not correct with that assumption, my second one is that you are trying to compile all java files, and use `.` as the classpath.  If so, then try,

```
@echo off
COLOR 08
title Compiler
"c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javac.exe" -cp . *.java
pause
```

This is a little dirty from a pragmatic point of view, because you are explicitly stating which version to use.. don't hardcode things like this..

java should be in your path.. if it is not, then press <kbd>Win+Pause Break</kbd> click "Advanced Settings -> Environment Variables" and add the "bin" folder to your "PATH" env variable, then you can do

`javac -cp . *.java` instead of that entire path.

Comment: I am trying to lead it to Jdk1.7.0_25 which is a Java program That I have downloaded. If spaces in any file system are touchy then why is there still a space when you put a \ in the middle of program files and a space after program\

Comment: you are able to put a space in there because you are escaping it, so it's rendered as part of the path, rather than an argument.

Comment: I believe Jdk1.7.0_25 is the JRE, and OP is trying to run all .java files using the current directory as classpath (`-cp .`).

Comment: thanks @iamnotmaynard - edited the question - pretty sure you're correct. hence `title Compiler`

Answer (score 0):

Check your environment variables on your system, as well as the run path from where you are running your server. It may be a configuration issue.

On windows 7, that would be Computer -> Right Click -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables.

Check to see that JAVA_HOME and/or PATH variable is set.

Comment: I do not see a JAVA_HOME in Environment Variables

Answer (score -1):

I am sure you must have tried using / instead of \
In case you have not, please try it.

If it still doesn't work, please provide more details on the error.
You may paste some of the stacktrace if you are getting en exception

Comment: It appears OP is using Windows.

Comment: I did try \ / both, It useally is a underscore instead of a space I have tried both.. I will post some pictures.